# Cómo evitar heap overflow en nodejs

Tags: array, nodejs

Estoy recogiendo registros de una base de datos de oracle. Es de unos productos. El caso, es que cuando relizo la petición, todo funciona perfectamente. Cuando llega el problema, es cuando envío esos datos a una función con la cual creo un array de objetos con los datos obtenidos. Por aquí pongo algo de código:
Función de controlador, donde realizo la consulta sql a oracle. Es algo simple, ya que estaba haciendo unas pruebas:

```
async function getStockFromMilena(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let c = await dbOraController.connect();
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS WHERE ENTIDAD = 9"
        let result = await c.execute(sql, {}, {});
        let structure = utils.dbStructureArray(result.metaData, result.rows);
        return res.send(structure);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

La función `dbStructureArray` es la que se ocupa de recibir los metadatos y las filas del resultado de la consulta:

```
function dbStructureArray(metadata, rows){
    try{
        let arrayObjects = [];
        rows.forEach((row, index) => {
            let dbObject = {};
            row.forEach((r, i) => {
                dbObject[metadata[i].name] = row[i];
            });
            arrayObjects.push(dbObject);
        });
        return arrayObjects;
    }catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Al insertar los objetos en el array me arroja este error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6148:000002B7D039E070]    15362 ms: Mark-sweep 1067.9 (1147.9) -> 1067.9 (1113.4) MB, 137.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.743, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[6148:000002B7D039E070]    15506 ms: Mark-sweep 1067.9 (1113.4) -> 1067.9 (1112.9) MB, 143.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.577, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000000F2F0B5C5C1]
Security context: 0x03447379e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: byteLength(aka byteLength) [000000CE683F9241] [buffer.js:531] [bytecode=000000534A1529F1 offset=204](this=0x0331a4f826f1 <undefined>,string=0x01d3a3f1af41 <Very long string[215438590]>,encoding=0x0344737be2e1 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
    3: fromString(aka fromString) [00000392DD313251] [buffer.js:342] [bytecode=0000005...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6756EC6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF6756C7416 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF6756C7D90 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF6759E189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF6759E17CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF675BC7F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF675BC645B v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2651
 8: 00007FF675CF02BB v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap+59
 9: 00007FF675CF2D6D v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString+77
10: 00007FF675A3DDA8 v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint+536
11: 00007FF6759D4EAB v8::internal::StringHasher::UpdateIndex+219
12: 00007FF6759FA2C6 v8::String::Utf8Length+22
13: 00007FF6756B07AC node::Buffer::New+4332
14: 00007FF675BF4382 std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::ZoneAllocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Umove+79442
15: 00007FF675BF580D std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::ZoneAllocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Umove+84701
16: 00007FF675BF4866 std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::ZoneAllocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Umove+80694
17: 00007FF675BF474B std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::ZoneAllocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Umove+80411
18: 000000F2F0B5C5C1
```

Lo que me deja iun poco loco, es que simplemente existen 78000 registros en esa base de datos... nunca antes me había pasado esto, y he manejado consultas más grandes. ¿Existe algún error en mi código que no esté viendo? ¿Hay alguna forma de tratar estos errores sin aumentar la `--max_old_space_size`?